# Вывести из столбца первый url

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица, `select * from table`:

```
ID |  name  |     photos                                                      | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | name 1 | {http://.../photos_1, http://.../photos_2, http://.../photos_3}
2  | name 2 | {http://.../photos_1, http://.../photos_2, http://.../photos_3}
```

Мне надо чтобы из столбца `photos` выводился только первый `url`, а остальные нет.

Чтобы было так:

```
ID |  name  |     photos         |
----------------------------------
1  | name 1 | http://.../photos_1
2  | name 2 | http://.../photos_1
```

Как сформировать такой запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вид `photos` похож на дефолтный вывод массива строк. То есть если у поля `photos` тип данных `text[]` или `varchar[]` или что-то похожее, то необходимо:

```
select id, name, photos[1] from tablename;
```

[Массивы postgresql нумеруются](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) с единицы, поэтому первый элемент будет под индексом 1. Если элемента массива нет либо сам массив NULL, то будет NULL в результате.

Comment: Да, у поля `photos` тип данных `VARCHAR(220)[] NOT NULL`. Я делаю по вашема примеры, но выдает ошибку `невозможно указать тип целого числа, потому что это не массив`. Может я не провильно спроектировал? Как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: какой в точности запрос получился?

Comment: Я разобрался, там была моя опечатка. Спасибо.